# Скрипт не работает при запуске по кронтабу

Tags: cron, amazon, резервное-копирование, linux

Есть скрипт:

```
. /path/to/config/backup.conf
export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/config/amazon.conf
aws s3 mb s3://$BUCKET
cd $FOLDER
aws s3 sync $FOLDER s3://$BUCKET$FOLDER --delete --exclude *.log
```

Если его запустить в консоли - все работает отлично: бакет на S3 синхронизируется с папкой $FOLDER.

Проблема заключается в том, что этот скрипт не работает при запуске по кронтабу. Насколько я понимаю при запуске по крону не работает команда export, так как нет окружения. Соответственно не подключается файл конфига и не происходит авторизация.

UPDATE:

Проблема была не в export, а в том, что к aws нужно было указывать полный путь:

```
/usr/local/bin/aws ...
```

Спасибо [[@Johny](/users/13738/johny)](/users/13738/johny) за помощь!

Comment: так а в чем вопрос то? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/path/to/config/amazon.conf" aws s3 mb s3://$BUCKET
```

и соответственно

```
AWS_CONFIG_FILE="/path/to/config/amazon.conf" aws s3 sync $FOLDER s3://$BUCKET$FOLDER --delete --exclude *.log
```

Comment: И пропишите полные пути к скрипту aws...